# How do I go about putting the returnCharacterStats function as a method in Preset?

Tags: python-3.x

Frankly, I have no idea what I am doing and trying to learn Python without a teacher has been the equivalent of banging my head into my desk multiple times hoping that eventually it will result in the code magically working. I need to know how I go about moving returnCharacterStats into Preset as a method, or better yet, if you could work out a way I could make the method by not having to call a bunch of functions within a method that would be great. I tried just putting it into Preset as a method as well as calling the function by doing 
`instantiateCharacter=Preset()` then
`instantiateCharacter.returnCharacterStats()`
but the console went 
`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'creature'`
pls help before I lose my sanity. A thorough explanation would be appreciated because I'll just dig a bigger ditch for myself if I copy paste a kind person's code without understanding what they did.

```
def getName():
 syllables = ['en','da','fu','ka','re','toh','ko','noh','tuk','el','kar']
 firstName = (random.choice(syllables))
 secondName = (random.choice(syllables))
 thirdName = (random.choice(syllables))
 return firstName+'-'+secondName+'-'+thirdName


class Preset():
 def __init__(self, creature, health=100):
     self.health = 100
     self.name = getName()

#Gives different attributes to each sub-class
class Barbarian(Preset):
 def __init__(self, power=70, specialAttackPower=20, speed=50, creature="barbarian"):
     super().__init__(creature, 100)
     self.power = power
     self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
     self.speed = speed

 def returnBarbarianStats(self):
     print(self.name,"the barbarian's stats:")
     print("Health:",self.health)
     print("Power damage:",self.power)
     print("Special attack power damage:",self.specialAttackPower)
     print("Speed:",self.speed)

class Elf(Preset):
 def __init__(self, power=70, specialAttackPower=20, speed=50, creature="elf"):
     super().__init__(creature, 100)
     self.power = power
     self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
     self.speed = speed

 def returnElfStats(self):
     print(self.name,"the elf's stats:")
     print("Health:",self.health)
     print("Power damage:",self.power)
     print("Special attack power damage:",self.specialAttackPower)
     print("Speed:",self.speed)

class Wizard(Preset):
 def __init__(self, power=70, specialAttackPower=20, speed=50, creature="wizard"):
     super().__init__(creature, 100)
     self.power = power
     self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
     self.speed = speed

 def returnWizardStats(self):
     print(self.name,"the wizard's stats:")
     print("Health:",self.health)
     print("Power damage:",self.power)
     print("Special attack power damage:",self.specialAttackPower)
     print("Speed:",self.speed)

class Dragon(Preset):
 def __init__(self, power=70, specialAttackPower=20, speed=50, creature="dragon"):
     super().__init__(creature, 100)
     self.power = power
     self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
     self.speed = speed

 def returnDragonStats(self):
     print(self.name,"the dragon's stats:")
     print("Health:",self.health)
     print("Power damage:",self.power)
     print("Special attack power damage:",self.specialAttackPower)
     print("Speed:",self.speed)

class Knight(Preset):
 def __init__(self, power=70, specialAttackPower=20, speed=50, creature="knight"):
     super().__init__(creature, 100)
     self.power = power
     self.specialAttackPower = specialAttackPower
     self.speed = speed

 def returnKnightStats(self):
     print(self.name,"the knight's stats:")
     print("Health:",self.health)
     print("Power damage:",self.power)
     print("Special attack power damage:",self.specialAttackPower)
     print("Speed:",self.speed)

#10 randomly generated characters.
i = 0
army = []
while i < 10:
 creatures = ['barbarian','elf','wizard','dragon','knight']
 creatureType = (random.choice(creatures))
 if creatureType == 'barbarian':
     army.append(Barbarian())
 elif creatureType == 'elf':
     army.append(Elf())
 elif creatureType == 'wizard':
     army.append(Wizard())
 elif creatureType == 'dragon':
     army.append(Dragon())
 elif creatureType == 'knight':
     army.append(Knight())
 i = i + 1
#I need to turn this into a method, or alternatively, simplify this code so this is replaced by a method that
#serves the same function but doesn't need the seperate functions within the subclasses.
def returnCharacterStats():
    instantiateBarbarian=Barbarian()
    instantiateBarbarian.returnBarbarianStats()

    instantiateElf=Elf()
    instantiateElf.returnElfStats()

    instantiateWizard=Wizard()
    instantiateWizard.returnWizardStats()

    instantiateDragon=Dragon()
    instantiateDragon.returnDragonStats()

    instantiateKnight=Knight()
    instantiateKnight.returnKnightStats()

returnCharacterStats()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the best OOP concepts here, your problem is that you are not making use of `polymorphism`. Replace `returnCharacterStats()` with this one:

```py
def returnCharacterStats():
    for solider in army:
        solider.returnStats()
```

Now change all stats returning function names to this `returnStats()`.

You are not realizing that you just have to ask the solider that please show me your stats right, it is duty of the solider to return his stats and not some other solider's stats. You don't have to name like `returnBarbarianStats()`, `returnElfStats()` etc, just name them `returnStats()`

Your object will return his stats not someone else's. I hope it is clear and detailed as you asked. I replaced your **15** lines into **2**

Comment: Ok so that does fix the main problem at hand, so thanks so much for that. However, on the list of things I need to do it says I have to make it a method of the character class-Preset(). At the bottom I put `initCharacter=Preset() initCharacter.returnCharacterStats()` and put returnCharacterStats() as a method in Preset but now it says `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'creature'`